# Geodatabase item not found: Valve_6__ATTACH exception thrown with Arcgis Runtime 100.0.13 while clone the map xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, arcgis-runtime, esri-maps, arcgis-runtime-net

need to use a map instance for another page so far clone the map instance and using that. but after updated the esri.ArcgisRuntime version from 100.0.8 to 100.0.13 facing a new error Geodatabase item not found: Valve_6__ATTACH while cloning the map with xamarin.forms. what are the alternative options or how to resolve this issue

```
var map = existingmap.clone();
```

Comment: Hava your tried other packages? I had searched the package and find the Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms package which is designed for the xamarin.forms. In addition, according to your description, the issue may caused by the package's version.

Comment: Yes, using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms package. the same code works with 100.8, the issue raised after the upgrade to latest 100.13

Comment: So as the below answer says, you can post it to the Esri Community.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known issue introduced at version 100.9. We are actively investigating.

Incidentally, while we try our best to monitor Stack Overflow (thanks for using the right tag!), please consider posting your ArcGIS Runtime questions at the [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-net-questions/bd-p/arcgis-runtime-sdk-dotnet-questions) (it also makes it easier for others to find the solution).